# Requesting Single Record from DataBase in Json Format using WCF Rest

Tags: c#, json, wcf-rest

```
   public Users GetUserById(string _id)
   {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
        conn.Open();
        string sql = ("select * from Books where id = " + _id);

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Users obj = new Users();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            obj.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
            obj.UserName = reader[1].ToString();

        }
        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
        return obj;
    }
```

I am puuling the info in Json Format but

Out Put for this is: {"UserName":"John","id":1}

Expected Out put is: [{"UserName":"John","id":1}]

I am missing the Square braces for the record
Whats the problem with my code?

Comment: the operation contract for above code is[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate="User/{id}",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Users GetUserById(string id);

Answer (score 3):

Your expected output i.e. `[{"UserName":"John","id":1}]`
represents the List of `Users` object.

So if you want such output should return from your function then you just need to return a List of user from your function.

But as your function name `GetUserById`, I think it should return single user( So I don't know why are trying to return an array of users from this)

But anyway you can get the expected output in this way

```
public List<Users> GetUserById(string _id)
{
   MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
   conn.Open();
   string sql = ("select * from Books where id = " + _id);

   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
   MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   List<Users> users=new List<Users>();
   Users obj = new Users();
   if (reader.Read())
   {
     obj.id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
     obj.UserName = reader[1].ToString();
     users.Add(obj);
   }
   reader.Close();
   conn.Close();
   return users;
}
```

Now whenever this `users` convert into json format, it will return the expected output.